# Como acessar apenas o atributo nome de todos os objetos do meu json em node.js com express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express.js, back-end

sou iniciante em programação e estou tendo um pequeno problema ao tentar acessar apenas os nomes dos objetos contidos no meu json.

ex json:

```
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "name": "Clube de Regatas Flamengo", 
            "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
        },
        {
            "name": "Clube de Regatas Vasco da Gama", 
            "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
        }
    ]
}
```

Queria retornar apenas o nome de todos os times que estão no json, porem só consigo acessar o nome de uma posição especifica, todos os dados de uma posição especifica ou todo o json.

ex do código(retorna todo o json):

```
const { log } = require('console');
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

server.use(express.json({extended: true}));

const readFile = () => {
    const content = fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json', 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(content);;
}

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const obj = readFile();
     res.send(obj.teams);
});

server.use(router);

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

ex do código(retorna apenas o nome de uma posição especifia):

```
...
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const obj = readFile();
     res.send(obj.teams[0].name);
});
...
```

Queria que ele me retornasse apenas o nome de todas as posições(algo tipo assim):

```
...
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const obj = readFile();
     res.send(obj.teams.name);
});
...
```

Porém dessa ultima forma ele me retorna uma tela em branco.

Answer (score -2):

O que você você precisa neste caso é utilizar uma função para mapear todos os elementos e retornar o valor desejado para cada elemento. Desde o ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), é implementado uma função para isso (simples e e extremamente útil):

`Array.prototype.map(callbackfn [ , thisArg ])`

**Referências:**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[ECMASCript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map)

**Utilização em seu caso:**

Para utilizar em seu caso e retornar apenas os nomes de cada time, o array de times `teams` deve ser mapeado, e a função de callback deve retornar apenas o nome para cada objeto que será iterado em seu array:

```js
const teamsName = obj.teams.map((team) => {
   return team.name;
})
```

ou de uma forma mais sucinta:

```js
const teamsName = obj.teams.map(({ name }) => name)
```